# Nested loop and conditional statement (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, loops, nested, conditional-statements

If you have a random matrix, for example a 5x5:

```
A(i,j) = (5 4 3 2 1
          4 3 2 1 0
          5 4 3 2 1
          4 3 2 1 0
          5 4 3 2 1)
```

And a second array:

```
B(1,j) = (4 5 6 7 8)
```

How can I then assign values of B to A if this only needs to be done when the value of B(1,j) is larger than any of the values from a certain colomn of A?

For example, B(1,1) = 4 and in the first colomn of A it is larger than A(1,1), A(3,1) and A(5,1), so these must be replaced by 4. In the second colomn, nothing needs to be replaced, etc.

Thanks already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab "find" may be of use to you.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html

If you aren't concerned about speed or efficiency, you could also set up a two nested for loops with a condition (i.e. an if) statement comparing the values of A and B.

If you only interested in column wise comparison to B, you could use the increment of the outer loop in the inner loop.

```
for i,...
 for j,...
   if B(1,i) > A(j,i)
       A(j,i)=B(i,j)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without any explicit looping using `bsxfun`:

```
A = [5 4 3 2 1
     4 3 2 1 0
     5 4 3 2 1
     4 3 2 1 0
     5 4 3 2 1];
B = [4 5 6 7 8];

A = bsxfun(@min,A,B);
```

Result:

```
A =

   4   4   3   2   1
   4   3   2   1   0
   4   4   3   2   1
   4   3   2   1   0
   4   4   3   2   1
```

In later versions of MATLAB (2016b and later) you can even omit the `bsxfun` and get the same result.

```
A = min(A,B);
```